# node tls, simulate socket ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

What i'm trying to do from my tests is to simulate ETIMEDOUT that should be caught by `socket.on('error', () => {...})`. In real word with 3rd party TCP server that im using, ETIMEDOUT is always caught by `error` event. Would like to mimic this situation in my tests also. Going through the `tls` docs, only candidate that could be used for this purpose is `socket.setTimeout` but it does not work how i would expect it:

```
describe('TCP timeout', () => {
  const TIMEOUT_AFTER_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1
  const socket = getActiveSocketFromSomewhere()

  it('should simulate timeout', () => {
    socket.setTimeout(TIMEOUT_AFTER_IN_MILLISECONDS, () => {
      console.log('are we here')
    })

    /**
     * This will trigger socket communication
     * with dummy TCP server where socket from
     * above will be used
     */
    return something()
    ...
  })
})
```

From console i can see that i was waiting for answer for `14ms` and that callback provided to `setTimeout` was executed, but after i can see that i received response from TCP server:

```
are we here
{ result: 'success', ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, That's how the behavior is.**

When the timeout is reached, the socket is not ended explicitly. It is clearly mentioned in the document and you'll receive a response whenever it is destined

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback

If you want to end the socket, you need to manually call `socket.end()` or `socket.destroy()` after `timeout` event is triggered

**Code:**

```
socket.on('timeout',function(){
    socket.end();
})
```

Comment: socket.end() doesnt exist in net Socket Node.js it is socket.close()